# Change Axis font size of a Excel Chart in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, fonts, charts, format

I'm trying to change the AXIS (not the axis title) font size of a existing Excel chart in vb.net. Image a chart with years on the X-Axis and Sales on the Y-Axis.. I want to change the font size of the YEARS (2000, 2001,...). Here's what I got:

```
Dim GRAPH1 as Excel.ChartObject

'GRAPH1 = Activeworkbook.Sheets(1).Chartbojects(Chart1)

GRAPH1.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).Font.Size = 10
```

But it doesn't work.

I know I can change the AXIS TITLE doing this:

```
GRAPH1.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 10
```

But that is not what I want. I hope you understand :)

Thank you very much! any kind of help would be much appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You left out TickLabels:

```
GRAPH1.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
```

Use Excel's macro recorder while doing something that you can't figure out the syntax. It will remind you of every little piece of the hierarchy.